# Automatic feature recognition in C#

Tags: c#, solidworks, solidworksapi

I am trying to automate the FeatureWorks "Recognize Features" command in an .sldprt file through a program written in C#.

I read the SOLIDWORKS API Help documentation, but found it very poor in information and examples.

I would be grateful if someone could guide me through the process with a simple working example that performs all the operations described in the help:

> - Instantiating a SOLIDWORKS connection (Opening SOLIDWORKS and a .sldprt file)
> - Getting the FeatureWorks object.
> - Recognizing imported features automatically (IFeatureWorksApp::RecognizeFeatureAutomatic).
> - Creating all of the recognized features (IFeatureWorksApp::CreateFeatures).

I've added and loaded all the necessary DLLs to my Visual Studio project.

I am interested in the automatic recognition mode with sheet metal features (all the features).

This is my starting point:

```
using SolidWorks.Interop.fworks;
using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;
using SolidWorks.Interop.swconst;

namespace SolidWorksAPIExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Instantiating a SOLIDWORKS connection
            SldWorks swApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SldWorks.Application")) as SldWorks;
            if (swApp == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to create SolidWorks instance.");
                return;
            }

            // Open a .sldprt file
            ModelDoc2 swModel = swApp.OpenDoc6("C:\\example.sldprt", (int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, (int)swOpenDocOptions_e.swOpenDocOptions_Silent, "", 0, 0);
            if (swModel == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to open the document.");
                return;
            }

            // Get the FeatureWorks object
            IFeatureWorksApp fw = (IFeatureWorksApp)swApp.GetAddInObject("FeatureWorks.FeatureWorksApp");

            // Recognize imported features automatically
            const int fwAutoEdgeFlange = 1;
            const int fwAutoHemFlange = 2;
            const int fwBaseFlange = 4;
            const int fwChamfils = 8;
            const int fwExtrudeOption = 16;
            const int fwHoles = 32;
            const int fwRevolve = 64;
            const int fwRibs = 128;
            const int fwSketchedBend = 256;
            const int fwVolume = 512;
            int options = fwAutoEdgeFlange | fwAutoHemFlange | fwBaseFlange | fwChamfils | fwExtrudeOption | fwHoles | fwRevolve | fwRibs | fwVolume | fwSketchedBend | fwVolume;
            int success = fw.RecognizeFeatureAutomatic(options);
            if (success == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to recognize imported features automatically.");
                return;
            }

            // Create all of the recognized features
            short createOption = (short)fwFeatureCreationOptions_e.fwAllowFailFeatureCreation;
            Boolean success1 = fw.CreateFeatures(createOption);
            if (!success1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to create recognized features.");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("All recognized features have been created.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not run your code, but what exactly isn't working for you or do you have a query about? On a cursory read you seem to have covered the basis you've asked about in your example code.

Comment: Best place to ask is cadoverflow.com